# Restrict Gitlab access by IP along with Nginx

Tags: security, nginx, gitlab

I got a public Gitlab installation running on Nginx and working, and i'd like to restrict its access to a whitelist of IP adresses.

I've tried to add a basic restriction in nginx like this :

```
location @gitlab {
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    allow XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX;
    deny all;
    ...
}
```

It kinda works as only allowed IPs can get through gitlab's web interface.
But when it comes to push stuff from these allowed IPs, i got this error :

```
Pushing to http://my.server:port/myrepo.git
POST git-receive-pack (451 bytes)
remote: GitLab: API is not accesible        
To http://my.server:port/myrepo.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'http://my.server:port/myrepo.git'
```

Weird. I also tried using ngx_http_geo_module, with the same result.
Can someone know how to get this done ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after looking at gitlab_error.log, i figured out that i also had to whitelist my server's public IP too :

```
[error] 13629#0: *380 access forbidden by rule, client: YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY, server: my.server, request: "POST //api/v3/internal/allowed HTTP/1.1", host: "my.server:port"
```

So in the end, my nginx config looks like this, and everything's now fine :

```
location @gitlab {
allow 127.0.0.1;
allow XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX;
allow YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY;
deny all;
...
```

}

Simple as that ...

Don't know if it's a bug or something as i'm using an old 7.6 version of gitlab. I'll run an update soon and will check this out.